# Add Spotlight Comments without tags on OS X Mavericks

Tags: macos, spotlight, finder-tag

I would like to add comments to files or folders. On previous OS X versions, there would be a text field to add comments that become searchable via Spotlight.

Now, in OS X 10.9 Mavericks the text field now says 'Add Tags' instead of Comments. When I add text in there, it shows up system-wide. This is not ideal when I only want to tag a single folder with a unique phrase. Is there any way to get File Commenting back?

Answer (score 5):

Turns out, commenting is still there, just hidden a little. Commenting is now a collapsible pane beneath the Name & Extension text field.

[image: Comments has moved to a collapsible pane]